# Google Sheets Script to allow cells to have data added to them but protect cells from being Deleted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with people deleting cells from google sheets instead of clearing content.
These sheets are static and have conditional formatting so when cells get deleted the conditional formatting gets all crazy.
I need a script that will allow me to prevent cells from being deleted but will still allow data to be entered and allow for data to be cleared with a clear content script I use.

I have several people entering data into column A of a worksheet in google sheets. One person will take that data and perform a function outside of sheets with it, and then clear the content so this process can keep repeating.

There are a lot of conditional formatting things tied to cells so the user can see if the data they entered is valid. If the end user runs this script to clear the content:

```
function ClearCells1() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('INT QC');
sheet.getRange('A2:A9660').clearContent();}
```

I want to make sure they are unable to "Delete" the cells in error because this causes conditional formatting to get all messed up.

Comment: I think it would be better if you could provide more details about the script that you are trying to implement, like a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to have a full idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question. Let me know if there is anything else I can add that may help clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following script

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var user = e.user;
  var oldVal = e.oldValue
  var newVal = e.value;
  var r = e.range;
  var rCol = r.getColumn();
  var ss = r.getSheet().getSheetName();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();

  if(user!="user@domain.com" && newVal==undefined && rCol==1 && ss==sheet[0].getName())
  // Replace the email address with your own after testing it so that you get access to delete info
  {
    r.setValue(oldVal);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You do not have enough permissions to delete data");
    // This generates the alert message, but you can delete if you do not need it.
  }
}
```

Any user should still be able to run your current script to clear the data in `column A` without any problem.

#### References:

- [Event objects (Edit)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [alert()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alertprompt)